# jQuery: How can I change the color only of the selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a selection list which in HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="language-list">
                    <option value="English">English</option>
                    <option value="German">German</option>
                    <option value="French">French</option>
</select>
```

With jQuery I would like to achieve that ONLY the currently selected option gets a red color. When you click on the selection list to see the other options, the other options shall keep their original color.

My current jQuery code looks like that:

```
$('#language-list').css('color', 'red');
```

How do I achieve that only the currently selected option gets a red color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:selected` pseudo-selector:

```
$('#language-list').find(":selected").css('color', 'red');
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/RZzNA/

**Documentation**

- jQuery `:selected` - http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('#language-list option:selected').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#language-list option:selected" ).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$("#language-list option:selected").text().css("background-color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :-
$("#language-list option:selected").css("color", "red");